# vscode, fail to connect when remote server asking for entering otp before password

Tags: linux, ssh, visual-studio-code

I fail to connect my university server via vscode. The issue is that connecting requires to enter an OTP and only then redirecting to the requested gate (and then ask for another password).

It seems that after the Vs gets a positive answer for the OTP, it immediately passes on to another stage (assuming connection has been a success).
Is there a way to config it to waiting for another password?

If not, where the source of extensions is? ( It seems like this is the right repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release, but it doesn't contain any logic file ). 
Thanks.

my config file:

```
Host gw.cs.huji.ac.il
  HostName gw.cs.huji.ac.il
  User davidponar%river
  NumberOfPasswordPrompts 6
  RequestTTY force
Compression yes
```

the trace:

```
[18:21:20.487] Log Level: 1
[18:21:20.492] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[18:21:20.492] win32 x64
[18:21:20.494] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+gw.cs.huji.ac.il", attempt 1
[18:21:20.494] SSH Resolver called for host: gw.cs.huji.ac.il
[18:21:20.494] Setting up SSH remote "gw.cs.huji.ac.il"
[18:21:20.515] Using commit id "5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a" and quality "stable" for server
[18:21:20.517] Install and start server if needed
[18:21:22.839] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[18:21:22.878] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[18:21:22.881] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 56087 gw.cs.huji.ac.il bash
[18:21:22.885] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[18:21:23.068] "install" terminal received data: "[2J[?25l[m[H


[H]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe[?25h"
[18:21:23.068] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[18:21:23.075] "install" terminal received data: "[?25l[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C
[80X[80C[H[?25h"
[18:21:23.538] "install" terminal received data: "[?25l[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C
[133X[133C[H[?25h"
[18:21:23.702] "install" terminal received data: "[?25l(OTP) Password: [?25h"
[18:21:28.956] "install" terminal received data: "2"
[18:21:29.712] "install" terminal received data: "0"
[18:21:30.443] "install" terminal received data: "6"
[18:21:33.438] "install" terminal received data: "5"
[18:21:33.972] "install" terminal received data: "1"
[18:21:34.335] "install" terminal received data: "5"
[18:21:36.001] "install" terminal received data: "[?25l
[?25h"
[18:21:36.250] "install" terminal received data: "[?25lPseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
[?25h"
[18:21:42.800] "install" terminal received data: "[?25lPermission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
[?25h"
[18:21:43.107] "install" terminal command done
[18:21:43.107] Install terminal quit with output: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
[18:21:43.107] Received install output: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
[18:21:43.109] Resolver error: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
[18:21:43.112] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"PermissionDenied","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
[18:21:43.114] ------
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, connecting through tunnel solves this issue.

try `ssh -CL 22222:river:22 user%river@gw.cs.huji.ac.il` and make sure your ssh settings file looks like:

```
 HostName localhost
 User username
 Port 22222
 NumberOfPasswordPrompts 6
 RequestTTY force
Compression yes
```

Comment: The ssh always worked for me fro the terminal, the issue was with the OTP when using the ssh in vscode.

Notice that you need `Host localhost` in the configuration in order for vscode to let you choose this option

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering the same problem, and here is a solution:

`ssh` to the remote machine, and remote the `vscode-server-insiders` directory.

```
cd ~
rm -r .vscode-server-insiders
```

Then it should works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure this out either.

If anyone does need a workaround you can:

1. Connect using VPN
2. ssh using a direct link to the server (hostname = river.cs.huji.ac.il)
   This way you can connect using the regular ssh method

Comment: Hi Dvir, connecting throuh tunnel solve this issue. try ```ssh -CL 22222:river:22 user%river@gw.cs.huji.ac.il``` and make sure your ssh settings file looks like: ```Host huji
  HostName localhost
  User davidponar
  Port 22222
  NumberOfPasswordPrompts 6
  RequestTTY force
Compression yes ```

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem where the vscode prompt does not show up during ssh connection, but none of the other answers were of help to me.

Using vscode settings `remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal` uses the terminal instead if the vscode prompt and I was able to login without difficulties anymore.